# Spring Security (java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate)

Tags: spring, security, jpa

I have problem with spring security.
I'm new in it, so can't understand why it work from time to time. (every 2nd or 3rd restart of main class i get null pointer from ProviderManager). As i think the loadUserByUsername method of my implementation of UserDetailsService do not calls by spring at that time.

**Error StackTrace**

```
2018-06-27 05:07:39.180  INFO 5556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 15 ms
2018-06-27 05:07:40.984  WARN 5556 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [101] milliseconds.
2018-06-27 05:07:42.285 ERROR 5556 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:164) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

**MyConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("hello")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig1.class);

    @Autowired
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")
    public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;

    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                                               UserDetailsService userDetailsService){ 
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder){
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UDservice implements UserDetailsService {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UDservice1.class);

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public UserDetails converter(User user) {
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl();
        userDetails.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        userDetails.setPassword(user.getPwd());
        userDetails.setEnabled(user.getEnabled());
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
        userDetails.setAuthorities(authorities);
        return userDetails;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (username != null){
         return  converter(repository.findByUsername(username));
        }
        else
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("null at name");
    }
}
```

Comment: let visitors to know what is solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control when Spring bean created.

So, if `setAuthenticationProvider()` be executed first, and next `configureAuthManager()` be executed, then you have `authenticationProvider` initialized

But if `configureAuthManager()` be executed first, and next `setAuthenticationProvider()` be executed, then `authenticationProvider` does not initialize, and you have `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

I also got this exception.
You will get this exception if you are not passing any authentication provider.
**If you are not providing authentication provider** *or* **if you pass null**

1. In my case and OP's case **Missed `@Autowired`** 
   (I was configured authorization and also authentication also but null was passed)

```
//Missed autowired annotation
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
```

And trying to inject null

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
  {
      auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider); // Null passed here
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin();
  }
```

2. You might have missed to inject authenticationProvider dependency
   `.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)`
   Or
   commented line
   `//.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)`